# How to write code to interface with the antenna on windows phone 8.1

Tags: c++, windows-phone-8.1, software-defined-radio

I want to create an app for windows phone capable of accessing the antenna used for cellular communications as a kind of software defined radio antenna with a limited band.  Ideally the app will receive and analyze signals similarly to how various SDR programs analyze signals on other bands.

My question is what lines of code, or library can I use to bypass the abstraction and access the radio antenna to receive signals on the appropriate band (850-950 MHz)?

The hardware I am working with is a Samsung Ativ SE with Windows 8.1 on Verizon, I am currently developing in c++ with Visual Studio 2015, but could change compilers easily

Comment: This is possible, hardware/firmware-wise?  Signals, what signals?

Answer (score 1):

You can't do that. Modern Mobile Phone Chipsets don't allow the CPU to access the raw RF signal.

Comment: That's what I thought:)

Comment: Point is that the bandwidth that modern mobile radio standards use are really too much for power-saving small CPUs like those in smartphones. To process 50Megasamples per second, you'd need a really capable x86 CPU with SIMD instructions. In hardware, with specialized DSP in silicon, this is different.